# How can i restart a dialog in Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have a NewContactIntent where the user enters data like first name and mobile number etc. I want him to be able to restart the dialog at any point. Therefore I have a RestartIntent so when the user says 'Restart' the RestartIntentHandler handles the request and should forward it back to the NewContactIntent. Here is the code:

```
const NewContactIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NewContactIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;

        if (request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED') {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent) 
                .getResponse();
        } else {
            const speechText = 'Kontakt hinzugefügt.';

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechText)
                .getResponse();
        }

    }
};

const RestartIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'RestartIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        return NewContactIntentHandler.handle(handlerInput);
    }
};
```

It doesn't work, when I try it alexa says the error message from the ErrorHandler.

**EDIT**

This example works and the BarHandler calls the FooHandler, so I don't understand why my case doesn't work:

```
const FooIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'FooIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Ich bin FooIntent!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const BarIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'BarIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        return FooIntentHandler.handle(handlerInput);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

### Adding a "restart" utterance

If you have only one intent then you could add **"restart"** or **"reset"** as utterances and will start the dialog from the beginning.

**Issue:** But if you have two more intents to be reset-ed, the utterance **"reset"** will trigger any of it. Even if you are in the middle of `IntentA` and then say **"reset"**, it might trigger `IntentB` who also has a **"reset"** utterance.

### Adding a RestartIntent

Adding a `RestartIntent` with utterances like **"reset"** or **"restart"** will definitely trigger `RestartIntent` and with the help of a `sessionAttribute` like `lastDialogIntent` will help you to understand which Dialog to restart.

**Issue:** The problem with dialog model is that, you cannot elicit a slot of a different intent from current intent. That means when you say **"restart"**, Alexa will trigger `RestartIntent` and you cannot respond with a `Dialog Directive` of the intent to be reseted.

> Note that you cannot change intents when returning a Dialog directive,
>   so the intent name and set of slots must match the intent sent to your
>   skill.

The tricky part is that, **the user has to say something that will trigger the required intent** again from RestartIntent, say `IntentA`.

```
Ex: 
User: I want to buy a car [triggered BuyCarIntent]
Alexa: Which color do you want? [first slot to be filled]
User: I want yellow color. [First slot filled]
Alexa: Which is your preferred make?
User: restart  [triggred RestartIntent]
Alexa: okay, what color do you want? [make the user respond in such a way that the user 
                                      speech will trigger the required intent again.]
User: I want yellow color.  [triggered BuyCarIntent]
```

If the user says just **"yellow"**, sometimes the intent might not get triggered depending on the design of your interaction model. Tune your interaction model and add utterances which can help you with this.

**Respond in such a way that the user will say something that will re-trigger the intent again.** Make use of the `sessionAttribute` to store and retrieve last used dialog intent Ex: `"lastDialogIntent":"BuyCarIntent"` to respond with appropriate question matching the intent.

Once it's re-triggered, dialog model will start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** possible solutions I can think of:
**1)** add utterances like "**restart**", "**start over**" in **NewContactIntent** and when the user will say restart, the dialog will automatically start from beginning.
**2)** add another restart intent but instead of writing a separate handler do this in **canHandle** function of **NewContactIntent**

```js
const NewContactIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NewContactIntent'
            ||handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'RestartIntent')
    },
```

**Note**: If you want that restart dialog to work only **after** the dialog of **NewContactIntent** is started then you can do this by setting a session attribute **state** to '**dialogStarted**' in **NewContactIntent** and then **updating** the **canHandle** function of **NewContactIntent** like following:

```js
const NewContactIntentHandler = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
            return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
                && ((handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NewContactIntent')
                ||(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'RestartIntent'
                && sessionAttributes.state === 'dialogStarted'))
```

Comment: Will this work when I add more Intents? Because the others would also need a "restart" utterance. 

PS: I have edited the code in the question. I try to directly return the NewContactHandler. But this also doesn't work.

Comment: Yes the 2nd code snippet will work even if you add more intents, just make sure you set unique attribute to sate in session of each intent that requires to be restarted

Comment: Ok i was trying to get it working with your 2nd suggestion. But it jumps straight to the else clause in NewContactHandler and doesn't ask me to fill the slots.

Comment: You cannot change intents when returning a Dialog directive.